# How to get form variables with special characters in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Really newbie question :)

I have a form that is:

```
<form class="contactform">
<input class="text" type="text" name="store_signup_form[name]"  />
<input type="submit" class="but" value="Try it!" /> 
</form>
```

If im post the data like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: urlsendMail,
type: 'post',
data: $('.contactform').serialize()
```

...

How can get these variables in PHP? Im trying but is not working:

```
$email = $_POST["store_signup_form'[name]'"];
```

Thanks

Comment: Rocket Hazmat has provided the correct answer below already. In general, what you want to do in such a situation is `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `name="store_signup_form[name]"` is how you send arrays in POST data.  PHP handles this as such.  That means that `$_POST['store_signup_form']` is actually an array!  So, you can just do:

```
$email = $_POST['store_signup_form']['name'];
```

Comment: Cool. Never knew that (never had to, but could be useful in the future). +1

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_POST["store_signup_form[name]"]` or `$_POST["store_signup_form"]["name"]`.